# Quickest Way to Access Value of Single Field TicDat Table

Tags: python

I have the following TicDatFactory.

```
solution_schema = TicDatFactory(
    plan=[["Period"], ["x", "x-plus", "x-minus", "y", "z"]],
    parameters=[["Parameter"], ["Value"]]
)
```

I create a TicDat from it and use that to store the outputs of my optimization model run like as follows (leaving out assignment of the "plan" table for this example):

```
sln = solution_schema.TicDat()
sln.parameters['Total Cost'] = mdl.ObjVal
```

I know in the future I can get the value of 'Total Cost' with `sln.parameters['Total Cost']['Value']`. However, I think this is clunky. Is there a quicker way to access that value without having to key twice?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer refers to [this](https://github.com/ticdat/ticdat/wiki/ticdat-defaultdict-enhancements). Remember, `sln.parameters` it itself a "dict-of-dicts". So `sln.parameters['Total Cost']` is merely a dictionary and thus `sln.parameters['Total Cost']['Value']` is the value associated with the `"Value"` entry of the `sln.parameters['Total Cost']` dictionary. (It's a little confusing because in this example, the `sln.parameters['Total Cost']` dictionary has the string `"Value"` as a key).

This begs the question of "but why does the assignment work when I don't specify a key to the inner dictionary". Thats answered in the link. A `TicDat` object, unless it is frozen, has some assignment overrides to allow it to behave more like a `defaultdict` when adding rows. It also has overrides to recognize the proper target field when adding/editing row to a table that has only one data field. The latter is being exercised in your example.